# How to target an element's value in a html web page which doesn't have id or class(using in a WPF c# application)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, wpf, html-agility-pack

i want to get the value(in code:x) of a div element in a local html web page that belongs to a wireless network radio. this div has no id or class or attribute.how can i do that in c# Windows Presentation Foundation?(the value is not fixed).i have searched a lot in the past few days. i know that maybe the best way is to use html agility pack to locate that specific line or to index all the div in the page and find this one by it's index.this is a part of that html page:

```html
<td rowspan="1">Link Capacity
  <div class="help">header=[Link Capacity]....</div>
</td>
<td>
  <div>x</div>
</td>
```

i just need to grab x which is a number.
also, class="help" was used many time in the page.
"Link Capacity" or "header=[Link Capacity]" are used in the code once. maybe they are the key on this solution.

Comment: Why don't you just give that div a class or id?

Comment: because i can't do that. i can't change anything on that page. i just can see it. like the page of any network Device or any web site on the internet. it's a hardware that i can work with it through it's web page.